# Curl Exception HTTP 415 : Unsupported Media Type Exception in JAX-RS and Jersey

Tags: xml, jersey, jax-rs

When I am running the below curl command(on Windows 7) I am getting an error (HTTP 415 : Unsupported Media Type Exception). As far as I know Jersey should be able to detect resource as I have indicated the content type as "application/xml" in the curl request. Can somebody help me in resolving this exception?

I am using the following curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-type: application/xml" -d @sample-input.xml    
http://localhost:8080/JAXRS/rest/Customer
```

My JAXB annotated Model Classes :

```
public class Customer {

  @XmlAttribute(required=true) 
  protected int id;

  @XmlElement(required=true) 
  protected String firstname;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }

  public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
  }

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  @XmlElement(required=true) 
  protected String lastname;

  @XmlElement(required=true)
  protected Address address;

  @XmlElement(required=true)
  protected String email;

  @XmlElement (required=true)
  protected String phone;

  public Customer() { }
}

@XmlRootElement(name="address")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Address {

  @XmlElement(required=true) 
  protected int number;

  @XmlElement(required=true)  
  protected String street;

  @XmlElement(required=true)  
  protected String city;

  @XmlElement(required=true) 
  protected String state;

  public int getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(int number) {
this.number = number;
  }

  public String getStreet() {
    return street;
  }

  public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
  }

  public String getCity() {
    return city;
  }

  public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
  }

  public String getState() {
    return state;
  }

  public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public String getZip() {
    return zip;
  }

  public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
  }

  public String getCountry() {
    return country;
  }

  public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
  }

  @XmlElement(required=true)  
  protected String zip;

  @XmlElement(required=true)
  protected String country;

  public Address() { }
}
```

I have written following resource using JAX RS

```
@POST
@Consumes({"application/xml","application/json"})
public Response createCustomerData(Customer customer){
  try {
    long customerId = 1;
    return Response.created(URI.create("/" + customerId)).build();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(e, 
      Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

Contents of sample-input.xml are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer id="1">
  <firstname>Duke</firstname>
  <lastname>OfJava</lastname>
  <address>
    <number>1</number>
    <street>Duke's Way</street>
    <city>JavaTown</city>
    <state>JA</state>
    <zip>12345</zip>
    <country>USA</country>
  </address>
  <email>duke@example.com</email>
  <phone>123-456-7890</phone>
</customer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.  Following JAXB annotations was missing from my Customer Model Class :

> @XmlRootElement(name="customer") 
>       @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)